# DBCP Connection Pool Active connections not closed

Tags: connection-pooling, jmx, apache-commons-dbcp

I am using DBCP connection pool and I have created a MBean to show the connection pool stats in Jconsole. What I have observed is that even if there is no activity on the application (means no page click, etc) the connection pool stats shows active connections.

[image]

The 16 NumActive connections we see above doesn't drop to zero. I am not sure why?
Can someone explain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the issue it was due to connection leakages.  The connections were obtained from the pool but were never returned to the pool.